# What's the best way to ensure privacy during communication between Cordova based mobile app and web server?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, encryption, get

I've built a mobile app based on Cordova, for both iOS and Android, i need to make secure communication between app and server. Request to server, in javascript, are like this:

```
    request.open("GET", 'http://url/service?firstElement='+elem+'&secondElement='+elem2, false);
```

I've tried to use RSA encryption generating public and private key locally using pidCrypt libraries, the 2048bits key requires too long time to be generates, so i've used 512bits.
The server is not be able to decrypt the message.

I'm looking for a better solution.

Comment: The simple solution is to use `https` (SSL). RSA encryption is generally used to encrypt keys, not data. For encrypting data the current best practice is AES.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using Send Ajax Request, Like This. I assume that you use php for Dynamic code (Server Side).

Here is Sample of HTML file which presant on your cordova, phonegap directory.

```
    <form method = "post" action = "#!">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <span class="help-block">Name</span><input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <span class="help-block">Password</span><input type="text" name="password" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <input type = "submit" value = "Save" class = "btn btn-success right" onClick="UpdateRecord();"/>
    </form>

    <script>
    function UpdateRecord()
      {
          var name = $("[name='username']").val();
          var host = $("[name='password']").val();
          jQuery.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "php/login.php",
           /* Or */
           /*url: "https://www.yoursite.com/page",*/
           data: "username="+ username+"& password="+ password,
           dataType: "html",
           cache: false,
           success: function(response){
                if(response == 'true') {
                    $.session.set("myVar", username);
                    window.location.href='profile.html';
                }
                else {
                    $("#errorMessage").html("Invalid Entry, Please Try Again");
                }   
            }
         });
     }
    </script>
```

And PHP File for Handle Query.

Please Not that code is not tested and it may change as per your need. You can perform any encryption method and use any function here.

```
    <?php
        include 'config.php';
        $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
        $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

        if(!empty($username) && !empty($password))
        {
                //$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$db.".users WHERE username='$username' and  password ='$password'");
                $result=mysql_query("select * from ".$db.".users WHERE email = '$username' ");
                while($data = mysql_fetch_row($result))
                {
                    $original_password = $data[3];
                    $salt = $data[4];
                    $hashedPass = sha1($salt.$password);
                    $fullusername = $data[16]." ".$data[17]; // Used Only for create full name session
                    if ($original_password == $hashedPass)
                    {
                        $_SESSION['username'] = $fullusername;
                        $_SESSION['useremail'] = $username;
                        $_SESSION['UserID'] = $data[0];
                        echo 'true';
                    }
                }

            }
    ?>
```

**Edit**

```
request.open("GET", 'http://url/service?firstElement='+elem+'&secondElement='+elem2, false);
```

Avoid to use GET method while sending sensitive data.

**Edit, Helpful Link**

[Local storage protection in phonegap application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20406291/local-storage-protection-in-phonegap-application?rq=1)

Comment: Just sending the data as POST does not provide security, it just makes it marginally harder to see.

Comment: @Zaph Yes I know but I think this is only way to post data to php page and then after encrypt it using desired method. If you know how to encrypt data in HTML then post it. its helps many people. And I think we use jquery for encrypt data and send it to php. Is it right way ?

Comment: As I commented, the simple solution is to use `https` (SSL).

Comment: @Zaph , Yes, in my code, I mention it in comment with Or. Is that right ?