# Phonegap sending form data to an external web application

Tags: cordova

I'm trying to send some data to a webpage from phonegap... Phonegap is accessing an external site and when you open a certain url I want my phone to gather some pre-saved data and fill the form with it...

Like for example, phonegap knows your email and when you open the url with the email form, the app automatically puts your email in the field...

I haven't found any way to do that yet and I can't use plugins since the page is external...

I'm looking for any viable workaround for this

Comment: For save data you can use Jquery Session
https://github.com/AlexChittock/JQuery-Session-Plugin

Comment: And you can also use HTML5 Web Storage, Info. Here http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25739446/whats-the-best-way-to-ensure-privacy-during-communication-between-cordova-based/25742380#25742380